# Can we write a code to automatically change the status from 0 to 1after 2 days in a database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table with column 'status' with a default value 0 in it.
After 2 days the value will be updated to 1.
Can we do it automatically in msql or php? 
Or should we update the table while logging in or something like that?

Comment: you need a Cron job. what OS are you using, and what web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have 2 ways for you to do this.

1. Server side: use cron job (*nix), Schedule tasks (windows) to execute a PHP or SQL script.
2. Client side: Use the same way: cron job (*nix), Schedule tasks (windows) but on your monitoring computer and run PHP link to check

Hope this help :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by calling a php script using [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). There are cron versions for windows, linux and other OS. The php script can modify the DB directly or call a stored procedure that will modify your entry.

For a pure PHP solution you can use [sleep](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function for two days, remember to set the max_execution_time to no limit, although it seems that the sleep time is not included in that. THis solution thought is highly inadvisable.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way is a cronjob. Another and less reliable way is to execute script on some action like you've already said. I'd suggest going with the first option. If you can't and choose the second option, keep in mind that there are no 100% guarantee that the value will be changed **exactly** after two days. And the offset really depends on how often that action is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have some date or timestamp for when the entry in the database was created? If you have that you can just check that and see if it was more than two days ago - and if so, say the status is 1.

Comment: For that in php we need an action like click, load etc, right? otherwise how can we do this automatically? with out any action like that

Comment: Well, i'm not sure what you are going to do with the status update from 0 to 1. Though if the only thing that the status field says is that the entry is older than two days, then one could omit the status field and just verify the "status" of the entries by their creation date. That is, the entries doesn't have to be updated after two days - it's enough that they were created with a "creation-time". If you, for instance, want to retrieve all entries which is "active" (status = 1), just query for all entries which is older than two days...